# C# and references in one Solution for all projects

Tags: c#, dependencies, log4net, structuremap

I use for example log4net and StructureMap dependencies in my project, now I want to split my project to more smaller projects in one VS solution, is it possible to use only one configuration for log4net and StructureMap configuration? Or must I add dependency to each project and set config files again for these plugins?

Each of these projects uses log4net and structure map, but the main project is a web app which calls other projects which is a C# library like:

```
Solution    
   - WebApp (ASP.NET MVC) project
        -- C# (Library) project
        -- C# (Library) project
```

I need log info to same file.

Comment: It depends on your needs, but usually it's enough to use one configuration in app.config for main project

Comment: You can add files as a link, they work the same as Shortcuts in Windows. In VS, it will link to the one physical file - This works well for code based files, configs, but not References

Comment: I need in best way, one reference in web app, not 3 references in each project

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the application will take the WebApp `web.config` configuration.

Comment: I add into the structure file config reference to the other projects? Because I set structuremap via DefaultRegistry.cs in DependencyResolution file in my project